# GDALWarp and Target Aligned Pixels Not Effective

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, batch, gdal-translate

I have two sets of TIFFs of different resolutions (100m and 1000m),  different alignment, and varying data types with corresponding no data values.  I need to downsample the 100m TIFFs to match the resolution and alignment of the 1000m TIFFs.  I also need to preserve no data values in each TIFF.

I am having a heck of a time accomplishing all three objectives in a straight forward manner without using multiple tools with repetitive resampling degrading the information.  Ideally, I would like to be able to accomplish all three objectives from the command line via batch, stand alone Python, or the Python window.

I have been able to achieve the correct cell size, no data value, and alignment, but by using awkward combinations of

1. GDAL_Translate

From inside QGIS and from a batch file running 
c:\OSGeo4W64\bin\GDAL_Translate.exe;

2. Align Rasters

Only from inside QGIS where the menu does not allow the specification of no data values for both the source and reference TIFFs leading to edge-effects as 100m TIFF no data values are included in averaging during resampling.  Will work only if 100m raster has already been resampled to 1000m and is then *resampled again* by Align Rasters.  I have not been able to run Align Rasters from any sort of command line in batch or Python.  I have not even found Align Rasters on my computer as Python nor as executable.

3. GDALWarp

Documentation seems to suggest that I could use GDALWarp specifying Target Aligned Pixels (-tap) to accomplish all three in one go.  I can run 
c:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe
from a simple batch file, but the -tap parameter is ineffective at aligning the result.

What I have tried is,

C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\GDALWarp -tr 1000 -1000 -tap ..\ROMS\BottomSalinity_max.tif -r average -srcnodata -32768 -dstnodata -32768 -of GTiff -overwrite bathy.tif bath_1000m_ROMS.tif

Can anyone see what I would need to change here?

I have to confess I am not sure I properly understand the single sentence in the documentation describing the purpose of the -tap parameter.

"**-tap:**  (GDAL >= 1.8.0) (target aligned pixels) align the coordinates of the extent of the output file to the values of the -tr, such that the aligned extent includes the minimum extent."

Other threads (and I have read a lot of them recently) suggest that -tap is the way to align rasters.  Am I just failing to supply the correct parameters or, is -tap not the way to align rastes?

Is there a way to access Align Rasters from the command line avoiding gdalwarp?  I do not need to warp -- just downsample and align.  I am only looking at gdalwarp as a tool through which I can successfully set the parameters for downsampling and aligning.

Comment: Could you  add the extent of `bath_1000m_ROMS.tif` from gdalinfo? Coordinates of all corners should be even thousand meters.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still working on this but I had the same issue with -tap.  For some reason, and maybe this is a bug, but the '-tap' doesn't work unless there is a space removed between the -tap and previous switch.

For example, I'm calling gdalwarp from a python script and this is an example of how I'm using it.  I have to remove the space after -t_srs EPSG:26918-tap.  Weird.  Full disclosure, I'm running an older version 1.9.2 so again may just a bug in the older version. I'm about to upgrade and test.

```
warpImage = ("C:\\GDAL\\gdalwarp.exe -ot UInt16 -of GTIFF -tr 1.0 1.0 -s_srs EPSG:32618 -t_srs EPSG:26918-tap -cutline %s -cwhere %s -crop_to_cutline -co TILED=YES -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW %s\\%s %s")%(fn, sql, cwd, infile, outTiff))
```

Comment: Heath,

I finished this project last Spring and have not worked GDAL again since.  Thanks for the note about spaces;  I will file that one away.  

Odd though, in my experience parsing parameters on a command line uses a specific syntax.  Of course, you are using  cutline where I was trying to align to an existing raster.  That and you are using the %s token to substitute parameters where my quick-and-dirty early example used hard-coded pathnames.

Good luck.

Regards,


Doug.